# How can I make something show after clicking in two different buttons in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, button, show, event-listener

I am really new in programming and I need help to solve a little issue, please. I started programming in Adobe Animate CC (ActionScript 3.0) and I want to know how to make a symbol appear only after clicking in two buttons. I can do that with just one button, but I don't know how to make it with two buttons:

```
button.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick)

function onClick (e:MouseEvent):void
 {
  graph.visible = true;
 }
```

Thanks,

João

Comment: Do you need to click those buttons at the same time?

Comment: You could add a boolean property indicating whether the first button was ever clicked or not. So when the user clicks on the second button, it just checks the boolean and if it's true then make the symbol appear.

Comment: How could that be a C# code ?!!!

Comment: are you using ASP.NET MVC or windows forms?

Comment: Do you need to be able to Turn the graphs off?

Comment: No, the buttons should be clicked one by one

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed now that the language isn't C#... I am using Animate CC, so I think that the language is ActionScript 3.0... How can I do that in ActionScript?

Comment: Possible duplicate of **Answered** : [How can I make a symbol appear after clicking in two different buttons in actionscript 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43632068/how-can-i-make-a-symbol-appear-after-clicking-in-two-different-buttons-in-action)

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to have a variable set to true for each button the first time they are clicked, and if both variables are true, then show the graph:

```
    var button1Clicked:Boolean = false;
    var button2Clicked:Boolean = false;

    function button1_Click(e:Event):void
    {
        button1Clicked = true;
        if(button1Clicked && button2Clicked) graph.visible = true;
    }

    function button2_Click(e:Event):void
    {
        button2Clicked = true;
        if (button1Clicked && button2Clicked) graph.visible = true;
    }

    // Rest of code omitted...
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I tried to use the code you gave me, but it didn't work... Should I do something else before adding the code you gave me?

Comment: Sorry, I only noticed now that the language isn't C#... I am using Animate CC, so I think that the language is ActionScript 3.0... How can I do that in ActionScript?

Comment: I don't know ActionScript. I see you've changed the language tag from C# to ActionScript so hopefully someone will help. Surely the logic is pretty much the same, though...

Comment: @JoãoTeixeira - I tweaked the answer for you.

Answer (score 1):

As Victor said above, you would create a boolean (let's call it oneClicked), initialized to false. Then each button would have the logic:

```
if (oneClicked == true)
{
    graph.visible = true;
}
else
{
    oneClicked = true;
}
```

Comment: But then wouldn't that also trigger if the same button was clicked more than once?

Comment: ah very true. looks like you already got there though, so I will upvote you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

HTML:

```
<div id="myElement">Click me!</div>
```

JS:

```
var elementIsClicked = false; // declare the variable that tracks the state

function clickHandler(){ // declare a function that updates the state
  elementIsClicked = true;
}

var element = document.getElementById('myElement'); // grab a reference to your element
element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler); // associate the function above with the click event
```