# How can I make a symbol appear after clicking in two different buttons in actionscript 3.0?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a little bit new in this programming stuff and I need help to program in ActionScript 3.0 (Adobe Animate CC). I want to make a symbol (graph) visible but only after clicking in two different buttons (button1 and button 2). I can make that with just one button, but I can't make it with two buttons... Can anyone help me? I tried this code but it isn't working as it should:

```
button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_1);
button2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_1);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    graph.visible = true;
}
```

Tom

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please post minimal working code to show us what you have already tried? That would enable us to help you. Thanks.

Comment: Well, I only have made this, but this isn't working as it should... 
    button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_1);
    button2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_1);

function fl_MouseClickHandler_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 graph.visible = true;
}

Comment: Thanks. Please put your code in the question, so you want the graph to be visible only once both the buttons are clicked?

Comment: Done. Yes, that's it. Only if someone clicks in button1 and button2 the image should be visible.

Comment: ok, do you want it in any specific order or it has to be button1 and then button2? And you want this with the same event handler?

Comment: No, it doesn't have to be in a specific order... I think that it can be with the same event handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way would be to do this, although there may be other ways to do it as well:

```
var isButton1Clicked:Boolean = false;
var isButton2Clicked:Boolean = false;

button1.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_1);
button2.addEventListener (MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_MouseClickHandler_1);


function fl_MouseClickHandler_1(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    if (event.currentTarget == button2)
        isButton2Clicked = true; 
    else if (event.currentTarget == button1)
        isButton1Clicked = true;
    if (isButton1Clicked && isButton2Clicked)
    {
        graph.visible = true;
        isButton1Clicked = isButton2Clicked = false;                    
    }
}
```

Note that I reset both the Boolean values to false, once the graph is visible so that it works like a reset.

On a side note, I would recommend to use better names for your buttons and your event handlers. Just best practice.

Hope this helps. Cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one thing: I inserted the code and tested it to make sure that it was alright, but it is saying something like: "1013: The private attribute may be used only on class property definitions". What should I do to fix that error?

Comment: @TomDavies Ah! Did not know your code was not in a class. I fixed my code above. If the answer works, please do mark as the selected answer and upvote so that it's helpful for other users. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks a lot! You really saved my day!

Comment: @TomDavies No worries! Glad I could help. Cheers.

Comment: Hello again! Sorry for asking you again, but I really need your help... I am working with multiple buttons and multiple graphs and I want to know how to remove the Event Listener and after I add it again, I want that he doesn't know which was the last button he clicked... It's just like remove an event listener and then add another one with the same function... Can you help me with this? Thanks, Tom